# React state update produces wrong result

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My `Fixtures.js` code:

```
const [selectedButton, setSelectedButton] = useState(1);

console.log("selected button = ",selectedButton);

const dateClick = (e) => {
      const clcikedDivId = e.currentTarget.id;

      // some code here!

      setSelectedButton(clcikedDivId);
   }
};

<div className={classes.roundDatesContainer}>
   {roundDates.map((item, index) => (
      <Button
         id={index + 1}
         key={index}
         lowOpacity={index + 1 !== selectedButton ? true : false}
         className="primary"
         customCssStyle={customCssStyle}
         click={dateClick}
            >
         {item}
      </Button>
   ))}
</div>
```

In my above code snippet, I have a round dates array which I'm iterating over with the `map` function and for each item I'm outputting a `Button` component that will have an `id` property equal to `index + 1` and a `lowOpacity` property of true in case the `index + 1` is different from the `selectedButton` value and false otherwise. In addition it has a `click` property that tells the button to execute the `dateClick` function when the button is clicked, and this function will execute some code (that doesn't matter for this question) and at the end of the fucntion the `selectedButton` value will be set to the clicked button `id`

My `Button` component:

```
function Button(props) {
    const { id, type, click, className, lowOpacity, customCssStyle } = props;

    console.log("id = ", id, " & low opacity from btn componenet = ", lowOpacity);

    return (
        <button
            id={id}
            type={type || "button"}
            onClick={
                click ||
                (() => {
                    return;
                })
            }
            className={`${classes[className || ""]} ${lowOpacity ? classes.lowOpacity : undefined}`}
        >
        <span style={{ ...customCssStyle }}>{props.children}</span>
            
        </button>
    );
}
```

As you can see in this component I'm setting a class of `lowOpacity` to the `button` in case that `prop` is set to true (which will be true when `index + 1` is different from the `selectedButton` value).

Now when the page first loads I get the following **correct** result:
[image]

(Note that I have react strict mode on which is why the `fixtures.js` is loading twice)

Since at first the `selectedButton` value defaults to 1 and `index+1` is equal to 1 that means all buttons except the first 1 will have their `lowOpacity` property set to true (though there is also an undefined value for a `Button` with an id of undefined which I have no idea where did that come from).

The problem is when I click on another button all buttons will now have the `lowOpacity` propert set to true:

[image]

For some reason when I click the second (or third) `Button` the `selectedButton` changes and become equal to the `id` of that clicked `Button` however as you can see from the above image all of the `Button` components now have their `lowOpacity` property set to true (plus one of undefined for a button of id undefined which I have no idea where that came from)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that IDs are treated as strings in the DOM, so here: `index + 1 !== selectedButton` (Where `selectedButton` is set from `e.currentTarget.id`)

You are comparing a number to a string, and they will never be equal, so `!==` will always return `true`

E.g.

```js
function example(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.id)
  console.log(1 === e.currentTarget.id)
}
```

```html
<input id="1" onClick="example(event)" placeholder="Click me" />
```

You will need to either:

- Convert the `index + 1` to a string before comparing the values
- Parse the ID as a number before the comparison
- Parse the ID as a number before storing it to `selectedButton`

I would recommend replacing:

`const clcikedDivId = e.currentTarget.id`

with

`const clcikedDivId = parseInt(e.currentTarget.id)`